# Enter in search box and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// catch enter code in search form in front page
$('#search').keypress(function (e) {
    var str = $('#search').val();
    var url = "default.aspx?search=" + str;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        location.href = url;
    }
});
```

I don't know why this code doesn't work what I expected " When you enter something in input#search, check if it's not empty then redirect to another page ". I try to enter every line in console without checking event, it works!

How can I fix this and why it doesn't work ? Thanks for your consideration time :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code (see: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Zsh/1/)). Can you provide an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but replacing keyup with keypress, it works now :)

Comment: Hei! I know this is an old question, but I am stuck and would really appreciate if you could help me out! My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700239/jquery-php-search-bar-for-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try .keyup() instead of .keypress().  Keypress is not an official specification, and can have unfortunate consequences in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Put your domain including http for location href to work correctly

```
    // catch enter code in search form in front page
$('#search').keypress(function (e) {
    var str = $('#search').val();
    var domain = "http://www.yourdomain.com";
    var url = domain+"default.aspx?search=" + str;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your example, maybe you should consider jsfiddle next time, it's great :)