# jQuery + PHP search bar for website

Tags: php, jquery, search

I am trying to make a search bar for a very simple website.
I have three pages : home, list and contacts. Header are the same for every page. It contains a search bar.
I have a very good piece of code that is working perfectly in the same page where are searchable list, but I can't figure out how to make it work from other two pages.
So far I have:

HTML for header:

```
<form id="search" action="katalogs" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" value="" />
        <span id="filter-word"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

HTML for list:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item red</li>
    <li>List item yellow</li>
    <li>List item blue</li>
    <li>List item green</li>
    <li>List item gray</li>
    <li>List item pink</li>
    <li>List item aqua</li>
    <li>List item brown</li>
    <li>List item orange</li>
    <li>List item purple</li>
</ul>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){ 

        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

        $("ul li").each(function(){

            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");

            } else {
                $(this).css("opacity", "1");
            }
        });

        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("You searched for" + filter);
    });
});
```

I can use PHP, so far I started with something like this:

```
<?php
    $search = $_POST['filter'];

    if (isset($search)) {
        echo "var search is $search";
    } else {
        echo "Nothing";
    }
?>
```

I am stuck. How to display the results? How to pass search string from home and contacts page to list page?
Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469233/enter-in-search-box-and-redirect-to-another-page but I am still stuck. Can somebody, please, explain?

Comment: I also found this : http://blog.grapii.com/2010/08/how-to-build-a-simple-search-filter-with-jquery/ but I still need the redirecting part :( Please, please, please, help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who tried to help. I figured out how to make it work.
My code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["filter"])) {
        $search = $_POST["filter"];
    } else {
        $search = "";
    }
?>

    <ul>
        <li>List item red</li>
        <li>List item yellow</li>
        <li>List item blue</li>
        <li>List item green</li>
        <li>List item gray</li>
        <li>List item pink</li>
        <li>List item aqua</li>
        <li>List item brown</li>
        <li>List item orange</li>
        <li>List item purple</li>
    </ul>

<script>

var test = "<?php echo $search ?>";
if (test.trim()) {
     var filter = test;
     $("li").each(function(){
         if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
             $(this).hide("slow");
         } else {
             $(this).show("slow");
         }
     });
     var numberItems = count;
     $("#filter-count").text("Atrasti " + count + " meklējumi " + "\"" + filter + "\"");
}

 $("#filter").keyup(function(){ 
     var filter = $(this).val();
     $("li).each(function(){
         if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
             $(this).hide("slow");
         } else {
             $(this).show("slow");
         }
     });
 });

</script>
```